# Python connect to sql server using AES decrypted password

Tags: python, sql-server, aes

I have an application (not mine) which has config file with an encrypted password and I guess it uses AES.

I would like to write a small python code to test connection using this encrypted password to make sure I can use it.

But I do not know how to use the encrypted password to the code

`````
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=192.168.10.1;'
                      'Database=AUIS;'
                      'uid=sa;'
                      'pwd=BR+vNRCyv0pxHF97Aad2JA==;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM AUIS.Table')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)````
`````

Answer (score 0):

Try to add ColumnEncryption

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=192.168.10.1;'
                  'Database=AUIS;'
                  'uid=sa;'
                  'pwd=BR+vNRCyv0pxHF97Aad2JA==;'
                  'ColumnEncryption=Enabled;')
```

Comment: It seem that plain text works but not encypted. I tested